# Content type of main-es2015

Tags: angular, apache, google-chrome, http-headers

I am using Angular 9.1.3 as framework and apache as server for my app.
After building new version of angular application I've started receiving this error in chrome:

*Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*

It is working fine with firefox. I've checked the response header in chrome and indeed type is "text/html", where it should be "application/javascript".

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 22 May 2020 12:55:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Mon, 18 May 2020 10:30:55 GMT
ETag: "341-5a5e9a86975c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 833
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Previous version of application has correct type of this file, so I have probably added something to angular app that couses this error. How can I force this type to be "application/javascript" ? Where is it defined ?

Comment: Check the response's content. It's probably that you have an error, and that the returned data is html for either an error page, or your index.html page. If it's after building a new version, try refreshing your browser's cache

Comment: Strangely, in response tab I have same thing as in _index.html_ which is confusing. How can I catch this error then ?

Comment: Is it a prod build, served though apache? Show your vhost. Did clearing the cache help?

Comment: Yes, it is prod build served on httpd. I am not sure what do you mean by vhost ?

Comment: I meant your Apache config.  Did clearing the cache help or not?

Comment: Okay, I was using ctrl+r to reload, but that wasn't clearing cache. I disabled cache in network tab and it started working. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to clean the cache (ex. disable cache in network tab) not just code reload (ctrl + r).

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to clear cache on cloudflare